# GridSearchCV to find best regularisation parameter : How to access both validation score AND training score

Tags: gridsearchcv

EDIT : Found solution by using rademacher regularisation dropout

I wonder if it is possible to tweak dropout, l1 and l2 regularisation with GridSearchCV.

My idea is to get training and validation score then calculate the minimum absolute relative error between them and get the values that minimize it.

But I am not sure how the split is used : When X,Y is plit into 5 K-fold, does all is use to train ? So if it is, how to inject validation data for testing ?

If not (if training & validation is create using X,Y), how to access score on validation to write my own scoring function with these data ?

Thanks a lot for help.

Regards

Comment: Ok I found solution to my problem. I must use Rademacher complex regularisation dropout wich permit to adapt dropout while training the model.

Comment: Were you able to access the actual validation scores though? I want to be able to plot the histories of the models but I cannot get the validation loss and acc for each epoch